# Summarizing Variables to apply PCA

Tags: r, datatable, pca, one-hot-encoding

In the data I need to analyze, character and factor variables are given. I used one hot encoding to transform character variables into factors and saved everything in a new data frame.
In order to perform a principal component analysis, I need to summarize the one hot encoded variables into the original variables but I don't know how to do it.

For example: the original variable "beds" had 4 unique values - "couch", "real bed", "airbed", "futon". through one hot encoding, each of these values is assigned to 1 or 0 per case, so the new matrix "beds" has 4 new variables which used to be the values of the variable "bed".
[this is how it looks after one hot encoding & scaling it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxInw.png)
How can I go back to the original format [like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDooA.png) to perform the PCA? By this I mean - how do I group the new variables so that a PCA makes sense? I was thinking of subcolumns [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2Lsf.png) but I don't know if that's the correct approach nor how to do it, because if I'd save the new variables into seperate dataframes like this:

df_mw_neu_bed <- cbind(Airbed = df_mw_scale$V1_Airbed, Couch = df_mw_scale$V1_Couch, Futon = df_mw_scale$V1_Futon, Real= df_mw_scale$`V1_Real Bed`)

& put them together, I am where I started and for the PCA I wanted to use "df_mw_neu_bed" and the other data frames i.e. for the room type (which would have the same format)

Thank you very much for your help! :)

Comment: Could you clearify your problem? If I understand it right, you want to restore data that are lost thanks to one-hot-encoding.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MartinGal I have to cluster an airbnb dataset and run a PCA beforehand. To do so I had to transform character variables into numeric variables through one hot encoding. this however, turns values into new variables. To perform a logically correct PCA, I need to summarize these new variables into the old ones/ group them somehow into the original variables. I was thinking of subcolumns but I am not sure on how to do it. If I don't then I'd try to describe the dataset by single bed and roomtypes (see a slice of the dataset in the pics above), which makes no sense logically

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can do it:

1. One-hot-encode the factor column from `iris` data set (= converting a categorical variable with multiple categories into multiple variables, each with a value of 1 or 0.
2. Convert back

```
# 1. one-hot encoding
iris_coded <- iris %>% 
    cbind(sapply(levels(.$Species), `==`, .$Species)) %>% 
    select(6:8) %>% 
    mutate(across(everything(), as.integer))

# 2. convert back 
w <- which(iris_coded==1, arr.ind = TRUE)
iris_coded$tranformed <- toupper(names(iris_coded)[w[order(w[,1]),2]])

iris_coded
```